# Accessing class name in a innerHtml made in js file

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am currently creating a cart with local storage.
When I add my products one by one, in the cart page, I do it with innerHtml :

```
productsContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="cart-product">
            <img src="../images/${item.tag}" alt="image product" style="height: 120px;">
            <div class="product-info-container">
                <div class="product-cross"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></div>
                <div class="product-info">
                <h4 class="product-title">${item.name}</h4>
                <h5 class="price">${item.inCart * item.price} €</h5>
                <div class="product-info-number">
                    <i class="bi bi-dash" id="bi-dash"></i>
                    <span class="quantity">${item.inCart}</span>
                    <i class="bi bi-plus" id="bi-plus"></i>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            `
```

The problem I have now is that I want to access my two icons (i class="bi-dash / i class="bi-plus") to increase and decrease the quantity. I tried to store them in variables with querySelctore and getElementById but it doesn't work. I get a null error.

Comment: How are you accessing the icons?

Comment: Off topic, but you'd be better to use a template element to store your markup, rather than putting it in to a string as you have now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine.

Here's a snippet showing the elements being logged in the console:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>

<script>
    let testElement = document.getElementById("test");
    testElement.innerHTML += `
        <i class="bi bi-dash" id="bi-dash">bi-dash</i>
        <i class="bi bi-plus" id="bi-plus">bi-plus</i>
    `;
    let biDash = document.getElementById("bi-dash");
    let biPlus = document.getElementById("bi-plus");
    
    console.log(test, biDash, biPlus);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```